# Console application with read only pure HTML UI

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, console

## Story

I would like to make an application with two parts:

#### 1. Console

Normal, bash-like CLI, implemented by me. That would be the way of communicating with the user, processing information, etc.

#### 2. HTML

I would like to print HTML somewhere on the screen. It would be updated by the console.

## Question

What should be the approach here? I'm not sure if a Windows Forms or WPF application is good here. IMO, that's too heavy. Ideally, a console application + some additional process would be used. But I've never heard of anything like that. Could you give me names of some frameworks / technologies where this would be possible?

Or maybe the other way - create this application but emulate console within it. I'm not sure if this is feasible...

Comment: Will your console application _always_ be accompanied with visual html view on the screen? Or you want to make it optional (can work without any html output whatsoever)?

Comment: @Evk - for some sorts of operations just the console would do - when I deal  with simple text. However, when it is more complicated or even contains images or references to YouTube videos (I use markdown converted to HTML), the view is preferred. It could be fixed though, for the sake of simplicity - the program could then **always show both the console and the HTML view**. Considering that, the HTML view would have to be embedded in an application...

Comment: However, if it's easier to just render it separately, I would go for this separate solution.

Comment: Do you need this to run on linux or that is windows-only?

Comment: Preferably that would work on OS X as well. Thus I seek something more portable... Just to highlight - no controls needed here. Just rendering HTML that I have in a `string`, that is all.

Comment: Last question would be - will your application be long-running (like a service) or user will just run it to perform some action after which it would be closed (together with html UI)?

Comment: The second option - the user will just run it to perform some action (in fact I'm doing spaced repetition learning, where *flashcards* [think of for example learning vocabulary or whatever] are in HTML). After that the user closes the app (together with the HTML UI) :)

Comment: I think the easiest and most cross-platform option would be to run local web server in your console application. You then just direct user to a page (like http://localhost:12345) or just open that page in browser automatically. This page polls your web server for updates every second (it's local with one user, so no problems with perfomance) and displays your html string.